# How do I use Rust's std::iter::iterate method

Tags: rust

The iter package has an iterate method [std::iter::iterate](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/fn.iterate.html) but I can't find an example of how to use it anywhere. Ideally I'd like to see how to return the result of std::iter::iterate as iterator for example, this method in ruby that returns whole numbers:

```
def whole_numbers()
    iterate(0) do |current|
        current + 1
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iterate(..)` returns the iterator itself, you can then use it directly, like that:

```
let mut it = std::iter::iterate(0u, |x| x+1);

for i in it {
    println!("{}", i);
}
```

If you need to pass this iterator around, you just need to mimic the return type of `iterate()`, which is :

```
pub fn iterate<'a, T: Clone>(seed: T, f: |T|: 'a -> T) -> Iterate<'a, T>
```

for example:

```
use std::iter::{Iterate, iterate};

pub fn create_counter() -> Iterate<'static, uint> {
    return iterate(0u, |x| x+1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem that I have is that I'd like to return the iterator and I'm not sure what the type signature should be.